# PHP include paths - include fails if file referred to with "./" prefix

Tags: php, include, include-path

I'm having issues with includes when the included file itself includes another file but refers to it with the dot prefix. For example there are three files - *inc1.php*, *inc2.php*, and *subdir/test.php*, the contents of which are -

subdir/test.php:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().":../:../.");
require("inc1.php");
```

inc1.php:

```
require("./inc2.php");
```

inc2.php

```
echo "OK";
```

This include tree shown here fails with a *failed to open stream: No such file or directory* error. It works if inc1.php contains a simple *require("inc2.php");*, without the "./" prefix. I added "../." to the include path as an attempt to get it to work, but that had no effect.

Other than performing the include with the "./" prefix, what is the solution here, assuming that inc1.php and inc2.php are not writable and you can only alter subdir/test.php? How can you still include inc1.php from within test.php?

For reference, I'm using PHP 5.2.9.

Answer (score 7):

Always include using the following style, unless you have a (**very**) compelling reason not to do so:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/inc2.php");
```

It saves all manner of headaches.

Comment: ... and in PHP 5.3 there is also a magic constant named `__DIR__` which is the same as `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: I know people still running PHP4, so I prefer not to use the latest and greatest constants for the sake of backwards compatibility, but you are right.

Comment: I am trying to use this with various scripts, e.g. Wordpress, which do not always follow that convention. Therefore the assumption taht inc1.php and inc2.php *cannot* be altered :) I need a solution that only edits test.php.

Comment: If Wordpress uses the calling style shown above in it's core, then someone needs to be shot. If it's in a plugin/theme, then *"cannot be altered"* is probably more than a little strong.

Comment: Yes, that's the include style Wordpress uses in it's index.php, and possibly other locations. There's also other popular scripts I've seen that use this in their core as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `chdir()` appears to work for this; changing test.php to:

```
chdir("../");
require("inc1.php");
```

It seems that "./" in inc1.php is interpreted as 'subdir/', so it looks for inc1.php only in the 'subdir' folder despite the include path.